# Why should ‘’zu’’ be used in this sentence?

Tags: dative, genitive

I can’t really ultimately understand the using of ‘’zu’’. Is zu in this sentence means the relationships between friends and colleagues? If so, what i can’t really don’t understand while always taking dative how can it comes to a meaning of genitiv?

> Die Stasi-Mitarbeiter verbreiteten Gerüchte, um Beziehungen **zu** Freunden und Kollegen zu belasten

Full context:

> Die Stasi-Mitarbeiter verbreiteten Gerüchte, um Beziehungen zu Freunden und Kollegen zu belasten. Sie erzählten diesen etwa, dass der Betroffene alkoholabhängig, homosexuell oder rechtsextrem sei – oder, besonders perfide, dass er Kontakte zur Stasi pflege.

Comment: of course Die Stasi-Mitarbeiter verbreiteten Gerüchte, um Beziehungen zu Freunden und Kollegen zu belasten. Sie erzählten diesen etwa, dass der Betroffene alkoholabhängig, homosexuell oder rechtsextrem sei – oder, besonders perfide, dass er Kontakte zur Stasi pflege.

Comment: "Beziehung *zu* jmd." == "relationship *with* s.o.".

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the Stasi is observing Max. Max has some friends, Albert, Bertha und Caroline. The Stasi does not want to put strain on the relationship between his colleagues
**zwischen seinen Kollegen**

> Albert <-> Bertha
> Bertha <-> Caroline
> Albert <-> Caroline.

Instead, they want to manipulate the relationship between him and his colleagues (*zwischen ihm und seinen Kollegen*). In other words, they want to manipulate his relationship **to** his friends and colleagues

**zu seinen Freunden und Kollegen**

> M <-> (A,B,C)

So here, *zu* is translated as *to*, just like the English version.

This takes the same case (Dativ) as a maybe more familiar example:

> Ich gehe zu ihm
>
> Die Beziehung zu Kollegen

Comment: I’d like to underscore that this is Dativ/dative, not Genitiv/genitive!